# Why is the Reflection showing this Main class as an Object and not an Applet?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, applet, japplet

I have two java files that I've compiled and packaged into a jar file.

```
// Main.java
public class Main extends GameWindow {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello reflection!");
  }
}

// GameWindow.java
import java.applet.Applet;
public abstract class GameWindow extends Applet { }
```

I'm using the Java Reflection library to print out the parent class of Main and GameWindow.

```
Class<?> main = Class.forName("Main");
System.out.println(main.getSuperclass() );

Class<?> gamewindow = Class.forName("GameWindow");
System.out.println(gamewindow.getSuperclass() );
```

I would expect `Main's` super class to be `GameWindow` and `GameWindow's` super class to be `Applet`, but when I run the above code, the output I'm receiving is

```
class java.lang.Object
class java.applet.Applet
```

What is causing these results?

Comment: You're running with an old version of the object code where Main didn't extend. Recompile and retest.

Comment: I just recompiled and tested and got the same results.

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure `Main` extends `GameWindow`? Try adding `GameWindow m = new Main()` and recompiling.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I'm not sure why, but when I added that line and compiled, I started getting the expected output. When I removed the line again, I kept on getting expected output, even for my original test case. Do you know if there's a reason for that, or was I just overlooking something?

Comment: It seems to me like you were using a version of the compiled `Main` class before you added that it `extends GameWindow`. As such, its parent class was `Object`. Only explanation that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that you are trying to look up the wrong class. Try using

```
Class<?> main = Class.forName("yourpackage.Main");
```

Comment: There is no package statement for `Main`, so it's placed into an unnamed package. Is there a way to refer to my `Main` class in the unnamed package?